# Error: userToken does not have a user_id or is not matching with user.id

Tags: vue.js, getstream-chat

I'm getting this error Error: userToken does not have a user_id or is not matching with user.id

Here's my code:

```
onMounted(async () =\> {
 try {
  const data = await $fetch(`${config.public.apiBase}/v1/chat/token`, 
 {
  headers: {"authorization": "Bearer " + user.value.token},
 });

    if (data) {
      userToken.value = data.token;
    }

 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
 }

 await setupChat();
});
```

```
const setupChat = async () => {
 if (!userToken.value) {
  console.error("User token is not available.");
  return;
 }

 try {
  if(!chatClient.user){
   console.log(userToken.value, 'userToken')
    await chatClient.connectUser(
  {
    id: user.value.id,
    name: user.value.name,
  },
   userToken.value,
  );
 }

    console.log(chatClient.user, 'chatClient.user')
    
    showOnline.value = true; // Display user online upon connection

 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
 }

};
```

Has anyone faced this issue before? I'm using vue3 and vue composition api

The token api returns the token that was generated by getStream. Not sure why it's not working

Comment: The solution was to convert the user.value.id to be a string.

```user.value.id.toString()```